# PHP cant see query string from RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

my `.htaccess` looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)$ /api.php?method=$1 [L,QSA]
```

my `api.php` looks like

```
class API {

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once('helpers.php');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        dd('hey');
    }

};

$api = new API;
$method = isset( $_GET['method'] ) ? $_GET['method'] : null;

dd($_REQUEST, $_GET);

if( $method && method_exists($api, $method) ){
    $api->{$method}();
}
else {
    exit("Nothing to see here governor.");
}
```

Yet when i visit the rewritten url e.g. `site.com/api/test` i see

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

if i change it to `/api.php?method=test` or `/api/test?method=test` i get

```
array (size=1)
  'method' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Why is the query string not able to be detected?

The server setup is apache 2.2, php-fmt 5.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since URI starting `api` is same PHP handler `api.php` I suspect it is problem of `MultiViews`.

Turn it off using this line at the start of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

`MultiViews` option is used by Apache's `content negotiation` module that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/api` can be in URL but it will serve `/api.php`.

Comment: To confirm, this did fix my issue!